# Fliter Json to HTML using Vue JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json to html using vue.js, I will like to display only Selections when odds and oddsw is greater than 1.44 for example

Json

```
{"soccerodds2017":[
{"Selections":"Chelsea","Odds":"1.44","Oddsw":"1.42"},
{"Selections":"Wolverhampton","Odds":"2.33","Oddsw":"1.25"},
{"Selections":"Walsall","Odds":"2.70","Oddsw":"1.50"}]}
```

Now the JS

```
$(function () {
    var JSONTableApp = new Vue({
        el: '#JSONTableApp',
        data: {
            Loading: false,
            Results: [],
            Ready: false,
            SearchInput: '',
            ResultsPerPage: 10,
            Data: [],
            CurrentPage: 1,
            NumberOfPages: 10,
            NumberOfResults: 0,
            NoResultsFound: false,
            PaginatedResults: [],
            OrderBy: 'Selections',
            OrderType: 'asc', //'asc', 'desc',
            UnableToLoadData: false
```

or when odds and oddsw is greater than zero.

Comment: look at array filter method

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed propery:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#JSONTableApp',
  data: {
    results: []
  },
  computed: {
    filteredResults() {
      return this.results.filter(function(item) {
        return item.odds > 0 && item.oddsw > 0;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Now you can use it in your html:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="result in filteredResults">
    ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i have     <tr v-for="item in Paginate()">  how to add result in filteredResults

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. What is `Paginate()` ? Can you edit your question code with all the code?

Comment: Paginate: function () {
                    this.NumberOfResults = this.Results.length;
                    var ResultsPerPage = parseInt(this.ResultsPerPage);
                    filtered_results = this.Results;

                },

Comment: Then you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) in your Paginate function.